# space character between quotes in bash script using XMLStarlet

Tags: xml, bash, shell, space, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to edit my xml file with a script in bash using the tool XMLStarlet.
So I want to delete a complete tag of my file, my problem is in the syntaxe of my command as following:

*xmlstarlet ed -d "/properties/structure name=\"preference\"" $1*

The tag is < **structure name="preference"** >

My error is:
*XPath error : Invalid expression
/properties/structure" "name="preference"*
The error is pointing on the first quote (")

I try to insert quote, backslash to make the space character acceptable but I don't find the way to make it works.
Can someone please help me on this subject? I didn't find yet a topic talking about this.

Thanks by advance

Comment: Can you provide the `XML` snippet fully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From:

```
<properties>
    <bla name="preference" >
    </bla>
    <structure name="preference" >
    </structure>
    <structure name="xxx" >
    </structure>
</properties>
```

the:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '/properties/structure[@name="preference"]'
```

produces

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<properties>
  <bla name="preference">
    </bla>
  <structure name="xxx">
    </structure>
</properties>
```